# Get file path in Golang

Tags: go

I need to read all files inside a directory, the structure is something like:

```
/data
   /folder1
     somefiles.txt
   /folder2
     /folder2.1
       somefiles.txt
   /folder3
       somefiles.txt
    ...
```

I tried the walk method, but walk reads the file and when it's done with the file it deletes the information and moves on to the next one. I really need to save it in an object (I'm using a slice of map) with all the data because I need to use an api endpoint and it's faster when I insert a lot of data than one by one (Inside the directories there are thousands of files so one by one takes a lot of time)

My idea is do a recursive function(like walk) but I don't know how to know the file path or I don't know if I can access with pointers inside walk function (I'm really new with GO) and save the file data in a global variable or something like that

Comment: have you tried using filepath.Glob(pattern) ? it looks up all the files matching a pattern and gives you a list. then you just need to loop through the list to read the files.

Comment: Show the code that you tried. [Walk](https://pkg.go.dev/path/filepath#Walk) and the [WalkDir](https://pkg.go.dev/path/filepath#WalkDir) (preferred) handle most scenarios.

Answer (score 1):

To use `fs.WalkDir()`, you just need to have your handler close over the variable(s) that you need to have populated when the execution of `fs.WalkDir()` is complete.

This, for instance, recursively walks the specified directory tree. Directories are ignored. A `map[string][]byte` is populated, keyed by the fully-qualified path of each file, containing the contents of each file.

```
package main

import (
  "fmt"
  "io/fs"
  "os"
  "path"
  "path/filepath"
  // "path"
)

func main() {
  root := "/path/to/root/directory"

  files := map[string][]byte{}

  handler := func(p string, d fs.DirEntry, err error) error {

    switch {
    case err != nil:
      return err
    case shouldSkipDir(p, d):
      return fs.SkipDir
    case d.IsDir():
      return nil
    case shouldSkipFile(p, d):
      return nil
    default:
      if fqn, e := filepath.Abs(path.Join(root, p)); e != nil {
        return e
      }
      buf, e := os.ReadFile(fqn)
      if e != nil {
        return e
      }
      files[fqn] = buf
    }

    return nil
  }

  err := fs.WalkDir(os.DirFS(root), ".", handler)
  if err != nil {
    panic(err)
  }

  for fqn, contents := range files {
    fmt.Printf("%s: %d bytes", fqn, len(contents))
  }

}

func shouldSkipDir(path string, d fs.DirEntry) (skip bool) {
  // TODO: set skip to true to indicate that this directory should be skipped.
  // If the current direcotry entry is a file and this returns true, then
  // the remainder of its containing directory are skipped.
  return skip
}

func shouldSkipFile(path string, d fs.DirEntry) (skip bool) {
  // TODO: set skip to true to ignore this file
  return skip
}
```